# What are the sayings of Hozai (the Seers) according to 2-Ch 33:19

Tags: word-study, history, referent-identification, 2-chronicles

> 2 Chronicles 33:19
>
> Also his prayer and how God received his entreaty, and all his sin
>   and trespass, and the sites where he built high places and set up
>   wooden images and carved images, before he was humbled, **indeed they
>   are written among the sayings of Hozai.**

Hozai in hebrew means "Seers".
Samuel, Iddo and a few others were referred to as "Seers" in scripture. This was a supposedly a book of the Seers and their visions.

1) What are these sayings of Hozai?

2) Where are these sayings today?

Comment: See [non-canonical books referenced in the Bible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-canonical_books_referenced_in_the_Bible).

Answer (score 1):

The name Hozai (חוֹזָי) in the MT doesn't necessarily mean seers (unlike חוֹזִים in verse 18), but is a proper name. For similar suffixes compare Amittai (Jonah 1:1) or Haggai (Haggai 1:1). The "Sayings of Hozai" was probably a book of prophecies (compare Amos 1:1, Jeremiah 1:1).

The LXX, however, does read this as "seers" and not as a proper name (τῶν λόγων τῶν ὁρώντων). Some prophets' books are described as "Visions" (Isaiah 1:1, Nahum 1:1) and this probably would have been one of them, but the omission of a proper name seems odd compared to the other books quoted in Chronicles, and so this textual tradition might not be the original one.

This book, like [many others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-canonical_books_referenced_in_the_Bible) mentioned in the Bible (which Lucian brings in his comment), no longer survives. A [prayer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prayer_of_Manasseh) attributed to Manasseh does exist at the end of LXX Psalms and modern collections of apocrypha, but is probably not the book quoted here in Chronicles.

Since this verse is the only source for what this book contained, not much can be adduced besides a very basic outline. Since the book was used as a source for Chronicles, the story of Manasseh here (which is absent from Kings) might have been drawn from the Sayings of Hozai (or the Chronicles of the Kings of Israel mentioned in the next verse).